# Configure docker images as executable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image `myapp:1.0`.
In mydocker file i have a `CMD` line to specify the main functionality of the image (which is to run a django application). 
What i want to know is if there is a way to pass a parameter do the image during the `docker run` call and accordint to the parameter, to execute a different command. 
For example:
`CMD[ { "run1": "run_script_a.sh" }, { "run2": "run_script_b.sh" } ]`
So i can run my docker image like so:
`docker run myapp:1.0 run1` #will execute run_script_a.sh
`docker run myapp:1.0 run2` #will execute run_script_b.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that any parameter added to docker run override automatically the [`CMD`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) defined in the image.

```
docker run myimage run_script_b.sh
```

That will run `run_script_b.sh` even though `CMD` defined `run_script_a.sh`.
(provided the [`ENTRYPOINT`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) was `[ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]`.)

---

That being said, you can try build 2 different images from the same Dockerfile, setting build-time variables with `--build-arg`:

```
docker build --build-arg RUN=run_script_a.sh ... --name run1 .
docker build --build-arg RUN=run_script_b.sh ... --name run2 .
```

With Dockerfile including:

```
CMD[ $RUN ]
```

If the CMD is at then end of the Dockerfile, the overhead in term of disk space will be minimum for those 2 images (instead of one image).

The only advantage is that you don't have to pass anything when running run1 or run2 images: they will launch their respective script.

Comment: Thanks! I feared that the plain answer will be no.  I already used the docker run command override option with a bash script but i was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add environment variables to docker run. You can use a generic run_script.sh then, which is starting the special script based on that variable, e.g.:

```
docker run -e "script=a" myimage
```

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables